# How to get full address of the point on the google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have points on the google map v3. I want to display information about this point (typ: Hotels) in infowindow (for example: name, address, link to website of place (if exist) and image).
Is it possible? Now i use this request, but there is no information about address, website address and image url.

```
var request = {
      location: clickedpoint,
      radius: document.getElementById('radius').value,
      name: "Hotel",
      types: ['lodging']
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google maps api supports what is called "reverse geocoding" which does exactly what you're looking for, given latitude/longitude: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding A little bit more correlation of data will be necessary to match the address against an actual business, but the address itself can help you along in that endeavor, especially if you already have that info stored, which according to your question, you do (having stated you already have the points in your application)